# Dual citizenship travel through Japan

Tags: visas, japan, dual-nationality

I am a dual citizen of Country A (currently here) and Country B. I will be travelling to Japan, country B has visa free access, where as country A requires a visa to enter Japan.

I will be getting a tourist visa on A’s passport for my vacation, but intend to go to B afterward on its passport.

There won’t be an issue at the Japanese exit immigration right? I intend to show the airline my B passport and then scan A’s passport at the automated gates.

At the same time how do people with dual citizenship travel through US/Canada that don’t even have facial recognition automated gates? Especially when they entered on A and the destination requires handing the airline B? (Assuming airline provides exit info to immigration).

Comment: Are both your countries happy for you to have both nationalities?

Comment: I've heard that the US has implemented logic in its entry-exit matching to associate arrivals and departures using different passports, but I haven't seen an authoritative source.  Since the US has been trying to tighten up their automated entry-exit matching for decades, though, it would be hard to believe that they hadn't noticed that this would be necessary.

Answer (score 5):

> I will be getting a tourist visa on A’s passport for my vacation,

That's not necessary. You can leave country A on passport A and enter Japan on passport B and then keep using passport B for the rest of your trip, until you make it finally back to A.

At the airport in A you present passport B to the airline for check in but you present passport A when you go through exit immigration.

Example: I have US and German passport. When I fly from Germany to the US, I use my US passport to check in for the flight, use my German passport at exit immigration, and then use my US passport again for final security checks at the gate.

That's all perfectly normal and accepted unless one of your countries has issues with dual citizenship.